# How often the phone checks for updates?

Tags: update

Just wondering how often Windows Phone checks for new updates?

I know it can be done via Zune Desktop, and I also know it checks for updates automatically. I just wanted to know how often it does that. I know it's more then a day appart. Two or Three I Think. I just don't remember exactly what the number is.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2):

Just [tweeted](https://twitter.com/vitor_canova/status/218120867387932673) to [WinPhoneSupport](https://twitter.com/WinPhoneSupport) and they said:

> @vitor_canova: *How often the phone check for updates?*
>
> @WinPhoneSupport *For OS the only info we have is that it regularly checks, no interval or certain time. App, it's checks at a predetermined time every day and should look for updates 10-15 mins after it's charging. ^EB*

"Regularly" is not the kind of answer I like. Maybe someone can improve.